# Integers not showing okay

Tags: c#, list

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlxX.png)

Anyone else faced the same issue. Eveything was okay and now `VS19` last version shows me this for `list Count`. Please don't give attention to the names I'm trying to fixed that from hour and a half.

Comment: I don't know if that's just me, but this is just some white blob to me. Could you add _in text_ what you get and what you expected instead?

Comment: its newString count shows -> 0x0000000c and I Expect 12

Comment: 0xC _is_ 12 in Hex. Which is odd, but correct. (Yeah I know - it's actually even. You know what I mean. I would have expected decimal display as default.)

Comment: but why is it showed like Hex and not like an Integer?

Comment: I don't know. But that's more a VS watch-window thing than anything else. Maybe even configurable by some setting.

Comment: @newbiedotnet is it? That image is unreadable. Post the code as *text*, and something that actually demonstrates the problem. Are you looking at an integer variable? A string? Are you adding numbers or appending strings?

Comment: I'm sorry but mister Fildor changed the way my question looked like. It was a link and you could see it. And I'm really thankfull to @Jonas Hogh for understanding my not good formed question. I don't know how I'm still with positive votes :)

Comment: You can revert the edit if you don't like it. But people tend to be more hesitant to click on links than look at an image. But even better is text, as we explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in the context menu when you right click the value in the watch window called "Hexadecimal display" - try turning it off